# .htaccess Redirect/Rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On a website, I have a `.htaccess` file setup for rules on rewriting the url. All of my content pages are generated dynamically, so there is only one file, `content.php`, and its basically generating the page based on a query parameter. The link structure of the site is then determined off of the main navigation.

So on content.php, its pulling the page from the database by looking at the URL. Behind the scenes, the URL would basically look like this:

www.website.com/content.php?page=my-page

However using rewrites, the url actually shows and displays like this:

www.website.com/my-page/

This works great, except for one issue I'm experiencing. You could pretty much add any directory you wanted before /my-page/, and the content for /my-page/ would still show. For example:

www.website.com/test1/test2/test3/my-page/

shows the same things as:

www.website.com/my-page/

If the actual link I want to use is: www.website.com/section/my-page/
how can I redirect any request that ENDS in /my-page/ to www.website.come/section/my-page/

I have tried using the following, but that ultimately ends up in an endless loop

```
RewriteRule (.*)/my-page/?$ http://www.website.com/section/my-page/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/my-page/?$ http://www.website.com/section/my-page/ [L,R=301]
```

By this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!my-page/my-second-page)(?:.+?/)?(my-second-page)/?$ /my-page/$1/ [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^.+?/(my-page)/?$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Also test this in a new browser to avoid old 301 cache.

Comment: I think this could work. How would I write it if I wanted "my-page" to be the first "directory? Example: www.website.com/my-page/ - if I remove the "/section" for each line above, the redirect doesn't work.

Comment: Lets say for example I have two different pages: my-page and my-second-page. I would want the URL for my-page to be www.website.com/my-page/ and I would want the URL for my-second-page to be www.website.com/my-page/my-second-page/ . If someone types in www.website.com/something/goes/here/my-second-page/ that should redirect to www.website.com/my-page/my-second-page/ - if someone types in www.website.com/some/other/stuff/goes/here/my-page/ that should redirect to www.website.com/my-page/

Comment: This rule works as is: RewriteRule ^.+?/(my-page)/?$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=302]  ------------ However the other rule doesn't work correctly. RewriteRule ^.+?/(my-second-page)/?$ /my-page/$1/ [L,NC,R=302] is resulting in a endless loop. If I go to: website.com/something/here/my-second-page/ it redirects to website.com/my-page/my-second-page/ but then enters an endless loop. If I go to website.com/my-second-page/ the page works, and it shouldn't, it should be going to website.com/my-page/my-second-page/

Comment: Still results in www.website.com/my-second-page/ to work, instead of redirecting it to www.website.com/my-page/my-second-page/ ---------- If I go to website.com/this/is/a/test/my-second-page/ that DOES redirect to website.com/my-page/my-second-page/ ------------If I go to website.com/my-page/test/my-second-page/ then that URL stays as is and doesn't redirect to website.com/my-page/my-second-page/

Comment: Ok based on my tests, that all works. Am I correct in stating that I would need to add a rule for each link on my site that my content.php page would process?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite `(.*)` is saying anything/you/like/before/my-page will match, and you also have a 301 permanent redirect `R=301` at the end of it which isn't needed.

In your .htaccess you can do the rewrites without the trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/section/([^/\.]+)$ /content.php?page=section&id=$1
    RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)$ /content.php?page=$1 [L]
```

And then in content.php:

```
$page = (!isset($_GET['page'])) ? 'indexPage' : $_GET['page'];

switch($page){

    case 'my-page':

 // process request for /my-page

    break;

    case 'my-other-page':

 // process request for /my-other-page

    break;

    case 'section':
    $section_id = (!isset($_GET['id'])) ? 'NONE' : $_GET['id'];

 // process /section/$section_id - i.e $section_id = my-section-1

    break;

    case 'indexPage':

 // process request for index page, i.e /

    break;

    default:

 // This should stop /the/anything/matching/my-page issue
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

In the above php, `$page` is set to `indexPage` if `$page` is empty or not set - and if `$page` is set but doesn't match anything in the switch/case section it returns a 404 header.

`$section_id` is handled the same way but set to `NONE` if it isn't set or is empty; like the `$page` variable, you can also send a 404 header if `$section_id` is sent but doesn't match anything.

Comment: How would this be done dynamically? If I have 100 pages on my website that content.php could display, I wouldn't want to have to type in 100 cases.

Comment: Just change `content.php` so that `$page` is evaluated via a call to your database. If no results are returned then you can send a 404 header as per above.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding this answer. It looks like with this, I would have to manually enter a case for each page on the site. The unique text for the page (I call it a slug) is only stored in the database (Example: for the about us page, about-us is stored). It isn't storing an entire URL, just "about-us". So I'm not seeing how this is automatically figuring anything out.

Comment: `$page` doesn't contain a URL - `$page` is set via the ternary `(!isset($_GET['page'])) ? 'indexPage' : $_GET['page'];`. If your request was `www,example.com/about-us` then thanks to the Apache rewrite then `$page` would only contain `about-us`

Comment: Isn't that giving me the same problem I am having now? Its look for $_GET['page'] from the URL, so in this url (website.com/this/is/a/test/my-page/ $page would = "my-page", same if the url was (website.com/a/different/test/my-page/) so its resulting in the same page, how would it be redirecting the URL to the correct one?

Comment: No, as per your question, if the URL was /section/my-page then $section_id would be set to my-page via the $section_id ternary.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, messed with regex for *hours* to no avail, following these answers. It turned out to be quite simple.

**Turn off MutliViews**

In short, in your server configuration, look for something like this...

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
```

...and change it to this...

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Of course, that line may look very different, depending on your file. The point is, put a `-` in front of MultiViews.

> NOTE: If you don't see any symbols on that line, just remove
>   `MultiViews` instead. Apache2 is all-or-nothing about use of symbols.

If you cannot (or don't want to) change server configuration, stick this line in your `.htaccess`...

```
Options -MultiViews
```

That fixed it for me!